# how to display a ee.Feature using folium?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, folium, jupyter-notebook

I try to display a country delimitation in a jupyter notebook using folium.

I try the following code

```py
#load country from LSIB
countries = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017');

#subset the sri-lanka
sri_lanka = ee.Feature(
    countries.filter(
        ee.Filter.eq('country_co', 'CE'))
    .first()
);

# Use folium to visualize the imagery.
mapid = image.getMapId(sri_lanka, {}, 'sri-lanka')

map = folium.Map(location=[80.773137, 7.873592])
folium.TileLayer(
    tiles=mapid['tile_fetcher'].url_format,
    attr='Map Data &copy; <a href="https://earthengine.google.com/">Google Earth Engine</a>',
    overlay=True,
    name='border',
  ).add_to(map)

map.add_child(folium.LayerControl())
map
```

and I get the following error

> TypeError: getMapId() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given

I don't really get the problem as in the documentation they describe it as:

> Get a Map ID for a given asset
>
> Returns the mapId call results, which may be passed to ee.data.getTileUrl or ui.Map.addLayer. Null if a callback is specified.

and this is exactly how I use it in `gee`.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `getMapId()` is done on the wrong object. Simply call it on your feature, with or without visualization params, like this:

```
mapid = sri_lanka.getMapId()
```